# 400 Bad Request (practicing socket python)

Tags: python, sockets, server, bad-request

I am trying this code below from some guy in youtube (I'm still practicing socket on phyton). the code returns 400 bad request. does anybody can help what happen?

```
import socket

mysock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
mysock.connect(('data.pr4e.org',80)) #ring web and assign extension
cmd = 'GET http://data.pr4e.org/romeo.txt HTTP/1.0\n\n'.encode()
mysock.send(cmd)

while True:
    data = mysock.recv(512)
    if (len(data)<1): #len data 0 means the end of string which means zero data received
        break
    print(data.decode())
mysock.close()
```

Comment: You might want to find out: 1. What headers are mandatory in HTTP and 2. How the language is actually spelled.

Comment: The problem has nothing to do with missing headers or spelling.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that you're separating lines in your request with `\n`, rather than `\r\n`. The end-of-line marker is documented in [RFC 2616](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2616#section-2.2).

This works just fine:

```
import socket

mysock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
mysock.connect(('data.pr4e.org', 80))
cmd = 'GET http://data.pr4e.org/romeo.txt HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n'.encode()

mysock.send(cmd)

while True:
    data = mysock.recv(512)
    if not data:
        break
    print(data.decode())
mysock.close()
```

**Update**

As pointed out in the comments, this request is technically incorrect. The following will also work, and is more representative of what an HTTP request should look like:

```
import socket

mysock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
mysock.connect(('data.pr4e.org', 80))
cmd = 'GET /romeo.txt HTTP/1.0\r\nHost: data.pr4e.org\r\n\r\n'.encode()

mysock.send(cmd)

while True:
    data = mysock.recv(512)
    if not data:
        break
    print(data.decode())
mysock.close()
```

Unlike the earlier example, this does include the `Host` header. The
only reason the original request works is due to the configuration of
the remote server.

Comment: Good catch! I was distracted by the fact that it works in either case :).